# how can i populate an array with json obects

Tags: php, json

I have a file, parts.json, which is a JSON file that contains an array of Objects that represents spare parts of some vehicles.

Here is a snippet of it:

```
[
    {
        "name": "\u0625\u0643\u0635\u062f\u0627\u0645 \u0623\u0633\u0648\u062f \u062e\u0641\u064a\u0641",
        "category": "\u0625\u0643\u0635\u062f\u0627\u0645\u0627\u062a",
        "quantity": "2",
        "price": "55",
        "id": 1756378,
        "shelf": "30",
        "slot": "173"
    },
    {
        "name": "\u0625\u0643\u0635\u062f\u0627\u0645 \u0623\u0633\u0648\u062f \u0645\u062d\u0645\u0644",
        "category": "\u0625\u0643\u0635\u062f\u0627\u0645\u0627\u062a",
        "quantity": "2",
        "price": "90",
        "id": 1181335,
        "shelf": "",
        "slot": ""
    }
```

In my **index.php**, I have a form with input of type `text` and an input is of type `submit`. I want to add search functionality so that whenever the `submit` is tapped, a table should be filled with all spare parts.

For this I have created two functions as shown below:

```
function getParts()
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/parts.json'), true);
}

function getPartByName($name)
{
    $parts = getParts();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (str_starts_with($part['name'], $name)) {
            return $part;
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

The problem is that when I use this code:

```
  $searchedPart = $_POST['searched-part'];
  $partToBeSearched = trim($searchedPart); 
  echo getPartByName($partToBeSearched)['name'];
```

I get the first occurence of the spare parts whose name starts with the entered prefix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). How is that a problem? According to the code, this is what the getPartByName() function has been written for. Looks good to me, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` in `getPartByName` can return only one element.

If you want more than one result, then you should return an array.

1. we define an array in the method
2. we add an element to the array for each element that correspond to the filter
3. we return the array

```php
function getPartByName($name)
{
    $matches = [];

    $parts = getParts();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (str_starts_with($part['name'], $name)) {
            $matches[] = $part;
        }
    }

    return $matches;
}
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/dK21a) (texts have been updated so that it's easier to understand than with encoded characters)

---

We can also write this without using a loop:

```php
function getPartByName($name)
{
    $parts = getParts();
    return array_filter(
        $parts,
        function($item1) use ($name) {
          if (str_starts_with($item1['name'], $name)) {
              return $item1;
          } else {
              return null;
          }
        }
    );
}
```

`array_filter` will apply the anonymous function to every item, it will remove values that don't match with the condition.

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/etI8e)